# Python PyQt update GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5

basically I am having trouble with Updating my new GUI.
Windows 10 | Python 3.8 | PyQt5

I got a class like

```
class My_GUI():
     def __init__(self):
          ...
     def callback_func1(self):
          self.tabWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.tabWidget.findChild(QWidget, "tab_2"))
          func2() # does some file operations in the background
          self.tabWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.tabWidget.findChild(QWidget, "tab_1"))
```

That callback_func1 is connected to a QPushbutton.clicked - Signal, so i push the button and it is running.

And here is my problem:
I would like to first switch the tab in the GUI to tab2, then call func2 (which is not a class method and not using the  object ) and then switch to tab1.

But what happens visually is: I just see the switching to tab1 in the end (after func2 needed its 2 minutes to run). So the first tab change never happens.

I think the problem is that the windows shows changes just after the  object was returned from the callback function

--> How would you solve this? Is there only the option to do something like Multithreading?

Comment: I suppose that `func2()` is a function that takes some time to complete. For *very simple* cases, you can just add a `QApplication.processEvent()` *before* calling that function, but in general multithreading (through QThread) is the most appropriate choice.

Comment: Hello musicamante, 

thanks for your impression, I also guess Multithreading will be the best choice for me, "func2" does some fle operations and yes it is important that its over before the algorithm continues with the GUI.
Thought there may be another solution and interesting to hear about processEvent, thank you!